# Android- await must not be called on the UI Thread

Tags: java, android, wear-os

I am trying to write a Wear OS app that records the IMU sensor data as a binary file and send it to the phone.

```
@Override
public void onDataChanged(DataEventBuffer dataEvents) {
    final List<DataEvent> events = FreezableUtils.freezeIterable(dataEvents);
     dataEvents.close();
     Log.e("List Size: ", String.valueOf(events.size()));
     for (DataEvent event : events){
         if (event.getType() == DataEvent.TYPE_CHANGED){
             Log.v("Data is changed", "========================");
             String path = event.getDataItem().getUri().getPath();
             if(SENSOR_DATA_PATH.equals(path)){
                 DataMapItem dataMapItem = DataMapItem.fromDataItem(event.getDataItem());
                 Asset fileAsset = dataMapItem.getDataMap().getAsset("File");
                 WriteToFilesFromAsset(mGoogleApiClient, fileAsset);
             }
         }
     }
     status.setText("Received!!");
}

private void WriteToFilesFromAsset(GoogleApiClient googleApiClient, Asset asset){
    String FileName = "_Activity.bin";

    File dataFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/DataFiles", FileName);

    if (asset == null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Asset must be non-null");
    }
    //The line below breaks the app
    InputStream assetInputStream = Wearable.DataApi.getFdForAsset(googleApiClient, asset).await().getInputStream();
   byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int byteRead;
    try{
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dataFile);
        while(  (byteRead = assetInputStream.read()) != -1){
            fos.write(byteRead);
        }
        assetInputStream.close();
        fos.close();
    }
    catch(IOException ex){
        Log.e("IO", ex.toString());
    }
    Log.i("Type", assetInputStream.toString());
    return ;
}
```

I get the error saying that await must not be called on the UI Thread.

I have found similar questions on SO, but none of them were able to fix my problem.

I would appreciate it very much if you can help me fix this bug.

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you try it on a different thread?

Answer (score 3):

The API you are using has a restriction on it that doesn't allow you to call await from the UI (AKA main) thread. There are several APIs in Android that do this to help protect you, the developer, from doing dumb things.  If you block the UI thread the OS can't paint your application so it looks like it is hanging to the user and will eventually cause an [ANR](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/anr) error.

In this case the task you are trying to do might take awhile so you need to get off the UI thread and complete the action in a background thread. There are several ways to do this. There is a `setResultCallback` method on the `PendingResult` you get back from `getFdForAsset` that will get around the await problem. However, you are later doing some I/O to save the data so that will also give you and similar error because you shouldn't be doing that on the IU thread either.  You will need to put the entire operation on a background thread.

Here is some docs for performing background tasks. https://developer.android.com/training/best-background

Comment: I know it's late but thank you so much! It helped a lot

Answer (score 2):

Try like

```
    private void WriteToFilesFromAsset(GoogleApiClient googleApiClient, Asset asset) {
    String FileName = "_Activity.bin";

    File dataFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/DataFiles", FileName);

    if (asset == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Asset must be non-null");
    }

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //The line below breaks the app
            InputStream assetInputStream = Wearable.DataApi.getFdForAsset(googleApiClient, asset).await().getInputStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            int byteRead;
            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dataFile);
                while ((byteRead = assetInputStream.read()) != -1) {
                    fos.write(byteRead);
                }
                assetInputStream.close();
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Log.e("IO", ex.toString());
            }
            Log.i("Type", assetInputStream.toString());
        }
    }).start();
}
```